# SonarQube Sanner for MSBuild error: Fail to get bootstrap index from server

Tags: .net, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm running `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe v4.2` from a build system to build my `.NET 4.6.1` project, and the server is `SonarQube server v6.7`. Both the systems are on `Windows Server 2012` with a secure connection between them.

The connection between the 2 systems is fine, and from the scanner machine I can browse the uri `https://mysonarqubeserver.com/batch/index` without any issues.

When I run the scanner with `NAnt` script from the build machine, the `begin` step works without any issue. But it always fails at `SonarQube-end` step saying the connection timed out! Below is the error message

> Fail to get bootstrap index from server

The console log is given below. Can anyone help fix the problem? (the whole setup works fine when run from a local dev machine)

```
 [exec] 22:35:05.546 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141
 [exec] 22:35:05.562 INFO: Java 1.8.0_102 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
 [exec] 22:35:05.562 INFO: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
 [exec] 22:35:05.562 INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
 [exec] 22:35:06.531 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
 [exec] 22:35:06.531 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
 [exec] 22:35:06.531 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
 [exec] 22:35:06.531 DEBUG: init keystore
 [exec] 22:35:06.531 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
 [exec] 22:35:06.906 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\xxxx\.sonar\cache
 [exec] 22:35:07.000 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\xxxx\.sonar\cache
 [exec] 22:35:07.000 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\xxxx\.sonar\cache\_tmp
 [exec] 22:35:07.000 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
 [exec] 22:35:07.249 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
 [exec] 22:35:07.249 DEBUG: Download: https://mysonarqubeserver.com/batch/index
 [exec] 22:35:12.578 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] 22:35:12.578 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
 [exec] 22:35:12.578 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] 22:35:12.578 INFO: Total time: 7.735s
 [exec] 22:35:12.578 ERROR: SonarQube server [https://mysonarqubeserver.com] can not be reached
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 INFO: Final Memory: 5M/245M
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: Caused by: connect timed out
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: 
 [exec] 22:35:12.593 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [exec] Process returned exit code 1
 [exec] The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
```

Comment: What is your MSBuild / Visual Studio version?

Comment: `MSBuild 14.0`, with standard path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MsBuild.exe`.But I'd doubt it has anything to do with MSBuild, as the build is working fine. Only SonarQube post processing is failing to connect to remote server.